# Show complete date range with NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to create this query to get all complete date on range and data with nulls if the date is not exist on the table

For example this is my **tbl_example**

**Original data:**

```
id | userid(str) | comment(str) | mydate(date)
1     0001          sample1      2019-06-20T16:00:00.000Z
2     0002          sample2      2019-06-21T16:00:00.000Z
3     0003          sample3      2019-06-24T16:00:00.000Z
4     0004          sample4      2019-06-25T16:00:00.000Z
5     0005          sample5      2019-06-26T16:00:00.000Z
```

Then:

```
select * from tbl_example where mydate between '2019-06-20' AND
DATE('2019-06-20') + interval '5 day')
```

how to output all the dates on range with possible null like this

**Expected output:**

```
id | userid(str) | comment(str) | mydate(date)
1     0001          sample1      2019-06-20T16:00:00.000Z
2     0002          sample2      2019-06-21T16:00:00.000Z
null  null          null         2019-06-22T16:00:00.000Z
null  null          null         2019-06-23T16:00:00.000Z
4     0003          sample3      2019-06-24T16:00:00.000Z
5     0004          sample4      2019-06-25T16:00:00.000Z
```

This is my sample test environment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5285/2

Comment: The examples were not clear.What is your orginal data and what output do you want?

Comment: sorry i highlighted the orignal and the expected output .thank you shawn.X ..

Comment: Just see my answer, I think the result it returns is just what you want. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just see my SQL as below:

```
with all_dates as (
select generate_series(min(mydate),max(mydate),'1 day'::interval) as dates from tbl_example
)
,null_dates as (
select
    a.dates
from
    all_dates a
left join
    tbl_example t on a.dates = t.mydate
where
    t.mydate is null
)
select null as id, null as userid, null as comment, dates as mydate from null_dates
union
select * from tbl_example order by mydate;
 id | userid | comment |       mydate        
----+--------+---------+---------------------
  1 | 0001   | sample1 | 2019-06-20 16:00:00
  2 | 0002   | sample1 | 2019-06-21 16:00:00
    |        |         | 2019-06-22 16:00:00
    |        |         | 2019-06-23 16:00:00
  3 | 0003   | sample1 | 2019-06-24 16:00:00
  4 | 0004   | sample1 | 2019-06-25 16:00:00
  5 | 0005   | sample1 | 2019-06-26 16:00:00
(7 rows)
```

Or the `generate_series` clause you can just write the date arguments you want ,as below:

```
select generate_series('2019-06-20 16:00:00','2019-06-20 16:00:00'::timestamp + '5 days'::interval,'1 day'::interval) as dates
```

Comment: hmmm im so confused this  "select generate_series('2019-06-20 16:00:00','2019-06-25 16:00:00','1 day'::interval) as dates" does not make the date range correct . but the data much closer to the expected output ..

Comment: @JakeGarbo `generate_series` is to construct a consecutive dates period,  and then you can left join your tbl_example data with it to get the missing dates, and then construct the null rows with the dates you get, finally union your origional tbl_example, you will get  the result you want.

Comment: my sample used rage of 5days  if I use generate_series(with the proper date range) i dont get the proper range so am confused. it shows upto 2019-06-27T00:00:00Z

Comment: I have updated my answer above,  you can write the second argument of `generate_series` with `your_date + 5 days interval`.

Comment: And my sql is just an example to clarify the method to solve your problem, when you understand this method, you can improve it to meet your needs. :D

Comment: Ok thank you i solve  it by adding the range date on last select statement thank you Shawn.X :)

Comment: Congratulations !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, userid, "comment", d.mydate
    FROM generate_series('2019-06-20'::date, '2019-06-25'::date, INTERVAL '1 day') d (mydate)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_example ON d.mydate = tbl_example.mydate
```

Result

Comment: im getting error : syntax error at or near "userid" Position: 35 
im using postgres v9.6 as test

Comment: the result has no 2019-06-22 and 2019-06-23 and it not get the proper range of 2019-06-20 to 2019-06-25 result .. it exceed to 2019-06-27

Comment: OK. I still did not understand your requirements properly. Now I think I do. You see the start and end dates in the generate_series function. I tested it and it the output is the same as you asked for.